# flood fill getting and RGB Value

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am writing a flood fill method to fill an image (an outline of a dog) with a red colour.

In my TestShellDlg.cpp is the flood fill method. CTestShellDlg::m_pScreenDib member is a CDIB32 bitmap class that contains the graphic and draws them.

I want to sample the current pixel and if it is not black (the colour of the outline) colour it red. This is the getter in the Dib32.cpp class:

```
void CDIB32::GetRGB(int x, int y, BYTE& r, BYTE& g, BYTE& b)
{
    if (x >= Width() || y >= Height())
        IERROR;

    int off = y * ByteWid() + x * 4;
    b = m_pBits[off];
    g = m_pBits[off+1];
    r = m_pBits[off+2];
}
```

And here is my floodfill method in the TestShellDlg.cpp class:

```
void CTestShellDlg::FloodFill(CPoint& mid)
{

    //while the current pixel colour is not black, set it to red and recursively loop
    m_pScreenDib ->GetRGB(mid.x,mid.y, (byte)& r,(byte)& g,(byte)& b);
        while(r !=(byte)0, g !=(byte)0, b !=(byte)0)
        {
            m_pScreenDib -> SetRGB(mid.x, mid.y,(byte)255,(byte) 0,(byte) 0);
            mid.x++;
            FloodFill(mid);
            mid.x--;
            FloodFill(mid);
            mid.y++;
            FloodFill(mid);
            mid.y--;
            FloodFill(mid);
        }

}
```

The problem is, it is saying r, g, b is undefined. I'm not sure why. Any help is muchly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare before you use them (you can't declare them inline in the parameter list)

```
byte r,g,b;
m_pScreenDib ->GetRGB(mid.x,mid.y, (byte)& r,(byte)& g,(byte)& b);
```